# UnCaught TypeError - Nested objects in Javascript? Why is this not allowed? Object literal notation works

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, object-literal

Playing around with some JS tests and I'm trying to instantiate some nested objects in my *v* namespace. As you'll see below, ClassA and ClassB work as expected. When I try and nest some objects under another property (*myCustomProperty*) I start running into issues! Could someone explain?

Below is the original code:

```
var v = (v) ? v : {};

v.someClassA = (function() {
   this.hello = function() {
        console.log("Class A Hello!");
    }
});

v.someClassB = (function() {
   this.hello = function() {
        console.log("Class B Hello!");
    }
});

// this all works! 
var myClassA = new v.someClassA();
var myClassB = new v.someClassB();


v.myCustomProperty = (function() {

    function someClassC() {
        this.hello = function() {
            console.log('C');
        }
    }

    function someClassD() {
        this.hello = function() {
            console.log('D');
        }
    }

    return {
        someClassC: someClassC,
        someClassD: someClassD
    }
});

// Uncaught TypeError: v.myCustomProperty.someClassC is not a function! Why?
var myClassC = new v.myCustomProperty.someClassC();
var myClassD = new v.myCustomProperty.someClassD();

myClassA.hello();
myClassB.hello();
myClassC.hello();
myClassD.hello();
```

If I change my declaration of *v.myCustomProperty* to use object literal notation, then it ALL WORKS! :

```
v.myCustomProperty = {
    someClassC: function() {
        this.hello = function() {
            console.log('C');
        }
    },
    someClassD: function() {
        this.hello = function() {
            console.log('D');
        }
    }
 }
```

I guess my question really is how would I make this work using the notation in my original snippet? Possible? Horrible practice to do it that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v.myCustomProperty` is a **function** that returns an object. You have to call the function first:

```
new (v.myCustomProperty().someClassC)();
//                     ^^
```

Otherwise, `v.myCustomProperty.someClassC()` tries to access the property `someClassC` of the function, and we all know (hopefully) that functions don't have such a property.

---

Or maybe you intended to execute the function immediately and assign the object to `myCustomProperty`?

```
v.myCustomProperty = (function() {
  // ...
}()); // <- call function
```

Comment: YES! Precisely! I just discovered the notion of Immediately Invoked functional expressions and just adding the (); to the end to invoke it right away. This fixes my problem. I guess this is how you would use constructor notation, in this case, instead of object literal? Is this bad practice though?